# Can someone please explain why i keep getting 4 for the result of this php while loop instead of 3?

Tags: php

I wrote this php while loop and expected the maximum size of the array in the loop to be 3 but it keeps filling the array with 4 random numbers. here is the code:

```
$array = array();
$number = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999);
while (count($array) <= 3) {
    if (in_array($number, $array)) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        $array[] = $number;
        $number = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999);
    }
}
echo count($array); // returns 4 instead of 3
```

I expected that since i told the while loop to run while the total number of items in the array is less than or equal to three it should stop executing bit it goes just 1 more time.

Comment: Think about what <= means, and how it's different than just < .....

Comment: Array indexes are zero-base, you actually count from 0 to 3.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone thanks. that explains it!

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone — the code doesn't explicitly look at the index at any point, only the count..

Comment: @Quentin Yes this code actually is independend from the indexes.

Comment: @prowl — It doesn't explain it. `count` counts the number of items in an array, it doesn't give the largest index in the array.

Comment: @quentin okay but when i say `while (count($array) < 3)` it returns 3. but 3 is equal to 3

Comment: @prowl — Because the loop stops when it is no longer less than 3. If it was 2 the loop would go round again and add another item to it, making it 3.

Comment: @Quentin I understand it now. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop runs until the count isn't *less than or equal to 3*.

Since you are adding 1 at a time, the first time it isn't less than or **equal to** 3 is when it is 4.

Answer (score 0):

This is evaluated at the start of each loop:

```
while (count($array) <= 3) {
```

First the count is 0, then 1, then 2, then 3.  That's a total of 4 iterations of the loop.  Each iteration adds an element to the array.  Resulting in 4 elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

please remove the "=" from "<=".  then you will have the desired value.

```
while (count($array) < 3)
```